# Error: CS0030 No se puede convertir el tipo 'System.Data.DataRow' en 'Clinica.consulta_externa.Paciente'

Tags: c#, devexpress

me dejaron realizar en clase de programación un pequeño programa de c# con devexpress. El profesor nos dio una explicación y la manera de usar el search pero el formulario de el solo era uno el mío actualmente posee 3, al buscar adaptar la explicación del profesor me aparece error en esta línea:

`Paciente pac = (Paciente)searchLookUpEdit1View.GetFocusedDataRow();`

Que pertenece a:

```
private void searchLookUpEdit1_EditValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Paciente pac = (Paciente)searchLookUpEdit1View.GetFocusedDataRow();
            var criterion = new GroupOperator() { OperatorType = GroupOperatorType.And };

            criterion.Operands.Add(
            new BinaryOperator("Paciente.Paciente", pac.Num_seguro, BinaryOperatorType.Equal));


            xpSignosV.Criteria = criterion;
        }
```

Estuve buscando un rato y me fije tener bien el Data Source, Display Member y el Value Member ya que en otras preguntas al foro mencionaban que el error podría venir de ahí

Alguien me podría iluminar? por favor

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. Tiene pinta de que estás recibiendo un registro genérico (una fila) y no es evidente para el programa cómo transformarla a una instancia de `Paciente`. Posiblemente deberías mapear los campos o instanciar la clase Paciente asignando los valores. Mi C# es nulo pero por ahí va la cosa...

Comment: Hola, gracias lo haré.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El inconveniente es que el método GetFocusedDataRow() devuelve un valor de tipo DataRow, y este no se puede convertir a tipo Paciente explicitamente, por lo que debes mapear las propiedades para que este funcione correctamente.
Podrias hacer esto:

```
var row = searchLookUpEdit1View.GetFocusedDataRow();
var paciente = new Paciente();
paciente.Name = row.Item["Name"];
```